# Вопрос насчёт js

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите в какую сторону копать мне что бы сделать ограничение на вывод, допустим у меня на сайте есть 100 блоков, у каждого блока свой id, пример:

```
<div class="bloks" id='5'></div>
```

Допустим с id = 5 у меня 30 блоков я сделал с верху маленькое меню:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="1">Блок №1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="2">Блок №2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="3">Блок №3</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="4">Блок №4</a>
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="5">Блок №5</a>
```

Подскажите простейший код что бы ограничить блока сайт написан на обычном html

Comment: Копать в сторону jQuery. А `id` должны быть уникальны. Нельзя, чтобы у нескольких блоков был `id="5"`, кроме того, `id` должен начинаться с буквы, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: А если сделать id="bloks5", но как мне быть если у меня их 30 шт, можно решить проблему что бы сразу все показывали у кого id="bloks5"

Comment: нельзя чтобы было 30 элементов с `id="bloks5"`.

Comment: `id` должен быть уникальным. `class` можно использовать сколько угодно раз. jQuery посмотрели? Там запросто: все прячете, потом показываете только те, у которых класс "blocks-5".

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function block(n)
        {
            $.get( "/block/"+n+".html", function( data ) {
                $( "#block" ).html( data );
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:block(1);">Блок №1</a>
    <a href="javascript:block(2);">Блок №2</a>

    <div id="block"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: в файликах /block/1.html, /block/2.html и тд. содержимое блоков